# How to properly update a Google Sheet chart data range via python?

Tags: python, charts, google-sheets-api

I've been recently struggling with updating a google sheet chart data range via python. There is a json payload [updateChartSpec](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateChartSpecRequest) that is supposed to do this and it seems like exactly the same thing as [addChart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AddChartRequest) which is working just fine for me, just with an additional `chartId` needed to specify.

Here is my code:

```
def add_sheet_chart(service, which_sheet, last_row):
    response = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=[], includeGridData=False).execute()
    sheet_array = response.get('sheets')

    # Get existing chart id here, if there are not charts, it's left as -1.
    sheet_id = 0
    chart_id = -1
    for sheet in sheet_array:
        if sheet.get('properties').get('title') == which_sheet:
            chart_array = sheet.get('charts')
            if chart_array:
                if len(chart_array) != 0:
                    chart_id = chart_array[0].get('chartId')
            sheet_id = sheet.get('properties').get('sheetId')
            break

    title = "..."
    bottom_title = "..."
    left_title = "..."

    requests = []

    if chart_id == -1:  # <- insert new chart here (works fine)
        requests.append({
                "addChart": {
                    "chart": {
                        "spec": get_chart_spec(sheet_id, last_row, title, bottom_title, left_title),
                        "position": {
                            "overlayPosition": {
                                "anchorCell": {
                                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                                    "rowIndex": 4,
                                    "columnIndex": 8
                                },
                                "widthPixels": 900,
                                "heightPixels": 600
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        })
    else:  # <- update existing chart here (doesn't work)
        requests.append({
            "updateChartSpec": {
                "chartId": chart_id,
                "spec": get_chart_spec(sheet_id, last_row, title, bottom_title, left_title)
            }
        })
        return

    body = {
        'requests': requests
    }
    service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body).execute()


def get_chart_spec(sheet_id, last_row, title, bottom_title, left_title):
    spec = {
        "title": title,
        "basicChart": {
            "chartType": "COMBO",
            "legendPosition": "TOP_LEGEND",
            "axis": [
                {
                    "position": "BOTTOM_AXIS",
                    "title": bottom_title
                },
                {
                    "position": "LEFT_AXIS",
                    "title": left_title
                }
            ],
            "domains": [
                {
                    "domain": {
                        "sourceRange": {
                            "sources": [
                                {
                                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                                    "endRowIndex": last_row,
                                    "startColumnIndex": 1,
                                    "endColumnIndex": 2
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "series": [
                {
                    "series": {
                        "sourceRange": {
                            "sources": [
                                {
                                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                                    "endRowIndex": last_row,
                                    "startColumnIndex": 2,
                                    "endColumnIndex": 3,
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "targetAxis": "LEFT_AXIS",
                    "type": "LINE",
                    "lineStyle": {
                        "width": 4
                    },
                    "color": colors['blue']
                },
                {
                    "series": {
                        "sourceRange": {
                            "sources": [
                                {
                                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                                    "endRowIndex": last_row,
                                    "startColumnIndex": 3,
                                    "endColumnIndex": 4,
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "targetAxis": "LEFT_AXIS",
                    "type": "COLUMN",
                    "color": colors['red']
                },
                {
                    "series": {
                        "sourceRange": {
                            "sources": [
                                {
                                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                                    "endRowIndex": last_row,
                                    "startColumnIndex": 4,
                                    "endColumnIndex": 5,
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "targetAxis": "LEFT_AXIS",
                    "type": "COLUMN",
                    "color": colors['green']
                },
                {
                    "series": {
                        "sourceRange": {
                            "sources": [
                                {
                                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                                    "endRowIndex": last_row,
                                    "startColumnIndex": 5,
                                    "endColumnIndex": 6,
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "targetAxis": "LEFT_AXIS",
                    "type": "COLUMN",
                    "color": colors['orange']
                }
            ],
            "headerCount": 1,
            "stackedType": "STACKED"
        }
    }
    return spec
```

The only thing that changes when I update the chart spec is the `last_row` variable and I just debugged it and it's a proper value. Here's a picture (some things are whitened-out but they are not related to the topic), the bottom part should include all week numbers but it only includes those weeks with which the chart was initially generated: [Incomplete chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvi3I.jpg)

I couldn't find anything similar anywhere asked, but seeing as there is little conversation about automatic google sheet charting anywhere, I was not surprised.
If it helps the charts are also published.

Comment: Could you please provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information, in which it is clearly specified what's the current state of the chart and what's the desired one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### A return statement is messing with your code!

When a chart is found (`chart_id != -1`), the code goes into an `else` block. At the end of this block, after appending the request for the chart update, you have added a `return` statement that is ending the function execution, so the code never gets to the `batchUpdate` call just below. Because of this, the chart is not updated:

```
    else:
        requests.append({
            "updateChartSpec": {
                "chartId": chart_id,
                "spec": get_chart_spec(sheet_id, last_row, title, bottom_title, left_title)
            }
        })
        return  # REMOVE THIS!
```

There's no reason for this `return` to be there. Remove it in order to get your chart to update successfully.

#### Reference:

- [return](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return-stmt)

Comment: Thank you! I guess this is irrelevant to google-sheets api then, sorry for the troubles.